# Spring State Machine does not maintain order in which actions are triggered when configuration is read from DB

Tags: spring-statemachine

StateMachineFactory is configured to read configuration from db repository. However then statemachine is created, and events are send to machine, the order of actions executed is not maintained. I suspect, it's because the results returned from DB are not in any particular order.

Following is a POC for the same. Logs are also attached

```
@Configuration
@EnableStateMachineFactory
public class Config extends StateMachineConfigurerAdapter<String, String> {
    @Autowired
    private StateRepository<? extends RepositoryState> stateRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TransitionRepository<? extends RepositoryTransition> transitionRepository;

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineModelConfigurer<String, String> model) throws Exception {
        model
                .withModel()
                .factory(modelFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public StateMachineModelFactory<String, String> modelFactory() {
        return new RepositoryStateMachineModelFactory(stateRepository, transitionRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public Action<String, String> action1() {
        return context -> System.out.println("Action1");
    }

    @Bean
    public Action<String, String> action2() {
        return context -> System.out.println("Action2");
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    StateMachineFactory<String, String> factory;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        JpaStateRepository stateRepository = context.getBean(JpaStateRepository.class);
        JpaTransitionRepository transitionRepository = context.getBean(JpaTransitionRepository.class);
        JpaActionRepository actionRepository = context.getBean(JpaActionRepository.class);

        JpaRepositoryState stateS1 = new JpaRepositoryState("UNPAID", true);
        JpaRepositoryState stateS2 = new JpaRepositoryState("DONE");

        stateRepository.save(stateS1);
        stateRepository.save(stateS2);

        var action1 = new JpaRepositoryAction();
        action1.setName("action1");

        var action2 = new JpaRepositoryAction();
        action2.setName("action2");

        actionRepository.save(action1);
        actionRepository.save(action2);

        JpaRepositoryTransition transitionS1ToS2 = new JpaRepositoryTransition(null, stateS1, stateS1, "TEST", Set.of(action1, action2));
        transitionRepository.save(transitionS1ToS2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var sm = factory.getStateMachine();
            sm.startReactively().block();
            sm.sendEvent("TEST");
        }
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
2022-10-12 22:01:19.474 INFO 58704 --- [ restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat started on port(s): 7082 (http) with context path ''
2022-10-12 22:01:19.482 INFO 58704 --- [ restartedMain] com.poc.Main : Started Main in 2.076 seconds (JVM running for 2.288)
Action2
Action1
Action1
Action2
```

Is there any way to achieve order when done configuration is read from DB?

Comment: @janne-valkealahti, have you encountered this before?

Comment: @hovanessyan, have you encountered this before?